# CATransaction begin/commit in loop not being honored, all happens at once

Tags: cocoa, core-animation

I'm working through the 4th ed. of the Hillegass/Preble Cocoa book and have hit a snag I can't understand in Core Animation.

In particular, I have the following loop that presents a list of images, supposedly one-at-a-time, into a layer-hosting view. The expected result is that I should see each image fly out one-at-a-time as `presentImage` is called. The actual result is that the view stays empty until the loop is complete and then the images fly out all-at-once. During the delay, I see the multiple log messages indicating the multiple calls to `presentImage`. When those log messages stop, indicating the loop is done, then all the images fly out at once.

```
// loop to present each image in list of URLs
// called at end of applicationDidFinishLaunching
NSTimeInterval t0 = [NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate];
for(id url in urls) {
    NSImage *img = [[NSImage alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
    if(!img)
        continue;

    NSImage *thumbImg = [self thumbImageFromImage:img];

    [self presentImage:thumbImg];

    NSString *dt = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%0.1fs",
                   [NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate]-t0];

    NSLog(@"Presented %@ at %@ sec",url,dt);
}
```

The `thumbImageFromImage` method does just what you'd think (creates a smaller image). The code for `presentImage` is as follows:

```
- (void)presentImage:(NSImage *)image
{
    CGRect superlayerBounds = view.layer.bounds;
    NSPoint center = NSMakePoint(CGRectGetMidX(superlayerBounds), CGRectGetMidY(superlayerBounds));

    NSRect imageBounds = NSMakeRect(0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height);

    CGPoint randomPoint = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMaxX(superlayerBounds)*(double)random()/(double)RAND_MAX, CGRectGetMaxY(superlayerBounds)*(double)random()/(double)RAND_MAX);

    CAMediaTimingFunction *tf = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];

    CABasicAnimation *posAnim = [CABasicAnimation animation];
    posAnim.fromValue = [NSValue valueWithPoint:center];
    posAnim.duration = 1.5;
    posAnim.timingFunction = tf;

    CABasicAnimation *bdsAnim = [CABasicAnimation animation];
    bdsAnim.fromValue = [NSValue valueWithRect:NSZeroRect];
    bdsAnim.duration = 1.5;
    bdsAnim.timingFunction = tf;

    CALayer *layer = [CALayer layer];
    layer.contents = image;
    layer.actions = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:posAnim,@"position", bdsAnim, @"bounds", nil];

    [CATransaction begin];
    [view.layer addSublayer:layer];
    layer.position = randomPoint;
    layer.bounds = NSRectToCGRect(imageBounds);
    [CATransaction commit];
}
```

The observed result is as if the `[CATransaction begin]` and `[CATransaction commit]` calls are bracketing the `for` loop rather than the call to `addSublayer` inside `presentImage`. In fact, I do observe the same all-at-once behavior if I remove the `[CATransaction begin]` and `[CATransaction commit]` from inside `presentImage` and instead bracket the `for` loop. Actually, I observe the same all-at-once behavior if I remove calls to `[CATransaction begin]` and `[CATransaction commit]` altogether.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good question.  What you're seeing is to be expected, given the way the exercise is architected.  The reason is that the animation (and drawing) of layers is done on the main thread, which is currently occupied loading images and creating thumbnails.  It's not until all of the images have been loaded and the thumbnails have been created that the main thread can actually get around to performing the animation you requested.  `CATransaction` doesn't have much of any impact in this single-threaded context.

We improve upon this in the next chapter (34, Concurrency) by preparing the images in a background thread (using `NSOperationQueue`).  This frees the main thread to display the new images and perform the animation as each image is loaded and resized in the background.

Comment: Thanks, Adam. I appreciate it. I'm glad that the behavior is to be expected, at least by someone :-). I find it quite strange.

It seems to me that each iteration of the `for(id url in urls)` loop should load an image and then animate the presentation of that image regardless of which thread is doing the work. It is not clear to me, either from the code or the `CATransaction` documentation, that the `CATransaction` calls might be ignored. I'll read that documentation more carefully soon though.

Comment: I wouldn't say that they're being ignored, but more that they aren't getting a chance to take effect, since the main thread isn't getting a chance to handle other events (such as the animation) until after -addImagesFromFolderURL: returns. This is a common thing to watch out for in Cocoa (and other frameworks): allowing the main thread to resume so that the UI can update and respond to user input.

Comment: Thank you again! Now that I've finished the Concurrency chapter, however, I have to say that I'm still confused. All images still appear at once, though faster (2.0s vs 3.0s). The UI updates all-at-once as if I've committed only one animation. To me, though, it seems that I've committed multiple animations, one in each pass through the loop. How would I begin to make the images appear one-at-a-time? (I did try moving the `addImagesFromFolderURL` out of `applicationDidFinishLaunching` and instead made it the target of a button. Still had same results.)

Comment: I found I had used  `[processingQueue addOperationWithBlock:...]` for the last block that included both `presentImage` and `setText` animations. I was supposed to use `[[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:...]` for that instead; that was the critical difference. Once I fixed that, the behavior was as expected.

I think this supports my "answer" below about the main thread handling animations. To test, I swapped a (correct) calls to `[processingQueue ...]`  with the `[[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] ...]` call and again observed the animations delayed.

Answer (score 0):

Well, after letting this bug the hell out of me for a few weeks, here's what seems to make sense, and seems (somewhat) obvious to me now, so hope I'm not too far off.

From the code given in my original question above, the main thread is responsible for all UI updates, including the animations, yet the main thread is effectively blocked from updating the UI until `presentImage` is done. This is true regardless of how we split `presentImage` into threads (as in Ch 34).

For example, if I have `presentImage` called as the target of a button rather than looping on it as in the code above, each animation begins as soon as I click the button and proceeds as I would expect regardless of how rapidly (or not) I click the button. Doing this ends up with multiple simultaneous animations as I would expect (and as I mistakenly expected from the original).

I'm not sure that I've captured the official technical details accurately, but this at least satisfies me as an answer.